# OSMNX - visualizing waterway together with footprints and ground

Tags: python, gis, geo, shapely, osmnx

I am trying to plot waterway together with ground (street network/map) and footprints (buildings). My **problem is that the waterways are large closed polygon areas**, which means instead of plotting a nice blue river with correct thickness it plots the river all over half of the figure (and there's no water there IRL...). This is what I have in Jupyter-Lab so far (example coordinates with few roads for quick test):

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(log_file=True, log_console=True, use_cache=True)
import numpy as np 

map_settings = dict(
    dist=805,
    edge_color='k',
    bgcolor='w',
    dpi = 300,
    point = (45.27386, 25.04644),
    default_width=2,
    )
fig, ax = ox.plot_figure_ground(network_type='all', 
    **map_settings,
    )

gdf_bldings = ox.footprints.footprints_from_point(point=map_settings['point'], 
    distance=map_settings['dist'], footprint_type='building',
    )

fig, ax = ox.footprints.plot_footprints(gdf_bldings, fig=fig, ax=ax, 
    set_bounds=False, save=False, show=True, close=False, 
    dpi=map_settings['dpi'],
    )


gdf_water = ox.footprints.footprints_from_point(point=map_settings['point'], 
    distance=map_settings['dist'], footprint_type='waterway',
    )

fig, ax = ox.footprints.plot_footprints(gdf_water, fig=fig, ax=ax, color='b', 
    set_bounds=False, save=False, show=True, close=False, 
    dpi=map_settings['dpi'],
    )

coslat = np.cos(np.cos(map_settings['point'][1] / 180. * np.pi) )
ax.set_aspect(1/coslat)
fig.set_figwidth(10)
fig
```

and it gives the following figure.

[image: OSMnx plot of ground network, building footprints and waterways]

I tried other places, and it does the same there.
**Is there any way to fix this to have a nice river as expected?** I tried to iterate through the shapely objects and figure out if I could remove the coordinates but it gets ugly pretty fast.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62285134/how-to-fill-water-bodies-with-osmnx-in-python/62287771