# Why are OSMnx footprints not filling up the entire image?

Tags: osmnx

I'm using the helper function provided [here](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/10-building-footprints.ipynb) with some modifications for distance and color.  I tried it without my changes and it has the same result. I noticed if I used the 'natural' tag that water ways will extend past the figure but I'm not using it in these, only 'building'.

Code being used:

```
import osmnx as ox
from IPython.display import Image
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)
bgcolor="#343434"
edge_color="#FFB0E2"
bldg_color="#F4FF6E"

point = (40.7154,-73.9853)
place = 'New York City, NY'
dist = 3000
dpi = 100

# helper funcion to get one-square-mile street networks, building. 
footprints, and plot them
def make_plot(place, point, dist, network_type='all', 
    bldg_color=bldg_color, dpi=dpi,
            default_width=0.5,
            street_widths = {
                "footway": 0.25,
                "steps": 0.25,
                "pedestrian": 0.25,
                "service": 0.25,
                "path": 0.25,
                "track": 0.25,
                "primary": 1,
                "secondary": 0.5,
                "motorway": 2 ,
                }):
    tags = {
        #'amenity':True,
        'building':True,
        #'geological':True,
        #'historic':True,
        #'landuse':['retail', 'commercial'],
        #'natural':True,
        #'waterway':True,
        }
    gdf = ox.geometries.geometries_from_point(center_point=point, 
          tags=tags, dist=dist)
    fig, ax = ox.plot.plot_figure_ground(point=point, dist=dist, 
              network_type=network_type,
              default_width=default_width, 
              street_widths=street_widths,
              edge_color=edge_color ,save=False, show=False, 
              close=True, bgcolor=bgcolor)
    fig, ax = ox.plot.plot_footprints(gdf, ax=ax, color=bldg_color,
                            save=True, show=False, close=True,
                            filepath="images/us_cities/{}-dist{}- 
                            dpi{}.png".format(place,dist,dpi), dpi=dpi)

make_plot(place, point, dist)
```

Example output:

1. Footprint does not extend to the edge of the image.  Empty margin on top and bottom of image
   [image: Footprint does not extend to the edge of the image. Empty margin on top and bottom of image]
2. Margin on left and right of image, footprint doesn't extend to edges.
   [image]
3. Large margin and footprint not filling image.  I noticed something in the logs while it was generating the map; two bboxes of different sizes are created.  They are bold in the log entries below:

- 2020-10-04 11:37:28 Configured osmnx 2020-10-04 11:37:28 **Created

  bbox 3000 m** from (40.7154, -73.9853):
  40.74237961006479,40.68842038993522,-73.9497049233066,-74.02089507669339
- 2020-10-04 11:37:28 Projected GeoDataFrame to +proj=utm +zone=18
  +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
- 2020-10-04 11:37:28 Projected GeoDataFrame to epsg:4326
- 2020-10-04 11:37:28    Requesting data within polygon from API in 1
  request(s)
- 2020-10-04    11:37:29 Pausing 0 seconds before making HTTP POST
  request
- 2020-10-04    11:37:29 Post
  http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%5Bout%3Ajson%5D%5Btimeout%3A180%5D%3B%28%28node%5B%27building%27%5D%28poly%3A%2740.688420+-74.020895+40.688420+-73.949705+40.742380+-73.949705+40.742380+-74.020895+40.688420+-74.020895%27%29%3B%28._%3B%3E%3B%29%3B%29%3B%28way%5B%27building%27%5D%28poly%3A%2740.688420+-74.020895+40.688420+-73.949705+40.742380+-73.949705+40.742380+-74.020895+40.688420+-74.020895%27%29%3B%28._%3B%3E%3B%29%3B%29%3B%28relation%5B%27building%27%5D%28poly%3A%2740.688420+-74.020895+40.688420+-73.949705+40.742380+-73.949705+40.742380+-74.020895+40.688420+-74.020895%27%29%3B%28._%3B%3E%3B%29%3B%29%3B%29%3Bout%3B with timeout=180
- 2020-10-04 11:37:37 Downloaded 25,341.0KB from    overpass-api.de 2020-10-04 11:37:39 Saved response to cache file    "cache/5c31a2f980a9dc4969b2dd7541ef5eff.json"
- 2020-10-04 11:37:39 Got    all geometry data within polygon from API in 1 request(s)
- 2020-10-04    11:37:39 196787 elements in the JSON responses (includes every node).
- 2020-10-04 11:37:39 Converting elements to geometries
- 2020-10-04    11:37:42 No outer polygons were created for    https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/7774552
- 2020-10-04 11:37:42    30055 geometries created in the dict
- 2020-10-04 11:37:42 376 untagged    geometries removed
- 2020-10-04 11:37:53 Created r-tree spatial index    for 29679 geometries
- 2020-10-04 11:37:54 Identified 29669 geometries    inside polygon
- 2020-10-04 11:37:54 10 geometries removed by the    polygon filter
- 2020-10-04 11:37:54 413 geometries removed by the tag    filter
- 2020-10-04 11:37:56 29265 geometries in the final GeoDataFrame
- 2020-10-04 11:37:56 **Created bbox 3600.0 m** from (40.7154,    -73.9853): 40.747775532077746,40.68302446792226,-73.94258590796792,-74.02801409203207
- 2020-10-04 11:37:57 Projected GeoDataFrame to +proj=utm +zone=18    +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
- 2020-10-04 11:37:57 Projected GeoDataFrame to epsg:4326
- 2020-10-04 11:37:57    Projected GeoDataFrame to +proj=utm +zone=18 +ellps=WGS84    +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
- 2020-10-04 11:37:57 Projected GeoDataFrame to epsg:4326
- 2020-10-04 11:37:57 Requesting    data within polygon from API in 1 request(s)
- 2020-10-04 11:37:57    Pausing 0 seconds before making HTTP POST request

[image]

Comment: Refer to StackOverflow's guidelines on how to ask questions on this site and how to provide a complete minimal working example to allow others to answer your question.

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you are calling `plot_footprints` at the end, but not passing it a `bbox` argument. So, per [the docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.plot.plot_footprints), it calculates the figure's bounding box to display from the spatial extents of the geometries. Some of the geometries that intersect your query area also extend far beyond it. Create a bbox that matches your query area and pass it to the plotting function.

Here's a simplified but complete working example.

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)

bgcolor = '#343434'
edge_color = '#FFB0E2'
bldg_color = '#F4FF6E'
point = (40.7154,-73.9853)
dist = 3000

bbox = ox.utils_geo.bbox_from_point(point, dist=dist)
fp = ox.geometries_from_point(point, tags={'building':True}, dist=dist)
G = ox.graph_from_point(point, network_type='drive', dist=dist, truncate_by_edge=True, retain_all=True)

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, bgcolor=bgcolor, node_size=0, edge_color=edge_color, show=False)
fig, ax = ox.plot_footprints(fp, ax=ax, bbox=bbox, color=bldg_color, save=True)
```

[image: figure]

Comment: Is there a way to give the water bodies a separate color from the building footprints?  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62285134/how-to-fill-water-bodies-with-osmnx-in-python) talks about filling water bodies but I think it was before v0.16 and if I add the 'natural' tag to the map above it fills them in but with the same color as the buildings.

Comment: Download a separate geometries_from_point then plot those footprints too.