# How to plot ANY kind of OSM water body (preferably with OSMnx)?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am trying  to make a Python script to plot different "layers" of a map, such as water, grass, rocks, etc. At the moment I am exploring the way of OSM through the package OSMnx, bringing the different geopandas.GeoDataFrame (gdf) through these kind of calls:

```
nature['rock'] = ox.features_from_point((latitude, longitude), dist=dist, tags={'natural': ['bare_rock', 'rock', 'scree']})
```

However, I cannot get to the point of bringing all the diferent water bodies to a single graph in a way that works with any point in the globe (including islands, or coasts). I have tried it  with the `tags={'natural': ['water', 'bay']}` and the `tags={'natural': 'coastline'}`, combined or by separate (and joined later). But it doesn't work.

I also checked that the prettymaps package doesn't seem to work fine on this cases (coasts or islands).

I expect something like this for the coast.

[image: Santo Domingo expected water bodies]
But I get this:
[image: Santo Domingo OSM returned water bodies]

Comment: Hard to provide specific feedback without seeing a complete minimal reproducible example. But, is this question/answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62285134/how-to-fill-water-bodies-with-osmnx-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You will find that coastline isn’t a polygon, it’s a way or line of points so won’t be rendered as a solid ocean. You would either need to join the ways to get a solid area which is difficult as there is often gaps in the data, or use processed data for sea or land bodies whic can be obtained from various sources. You could also import the ways into qgis and manualy join and check the polygons and then export to geojson for use in your python script. However the file size for un simplified sea polygons is around 1.5 gb on my version of the data.